# Doctrine2 Entity Issue

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have the following issue. I am using Symfony2. In my program, I use two classes: `Users` and `Posts`. My `Post` entity has a property called `uploader(A User Object)`.

The problem occours when I try to insert a new `Post`. For some reason instead of inserting a new `Post` with the same `User` object as logged in the session, it inserts a new `User` object in the database and sets the new `Post` object with that user id.

Here are some samples of the code:

```
/**
  * Posts
  *
  * @ORM\Table(name="posts")
  * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Main\ClientBundle\Entity\PostsRepository")
  */
class Posts {
    /**
     * @var \Users
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Users",cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="uploader", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $uploader;

    /**
     * Set uploader
     *
     * @param \Main\ClientBundle\Entity\Users $uploader
     * @return Posts
     */
    public function setUploader(\Main\ClientBundle\Entity\Users $uploader = null)
    {
        $this->uploader = $uploader;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

This is the code that inserts the new `Post` into the database:

```
$post = new Posts();
$post->setType(0);
$post->setDate(new \DateTime());
$post->setTitle($postTitle);
$post->setSafeForWork($isSafe);

$session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
$post->setUploader($session->get('user'));
$post->setImage($hashFileName);

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->persist($post);
$em->flush();
```

As you can see the the user is taken from the session. Why does this code creates a new `User` instance?

Comment: Can you paste the relevant parts of your `User` class as well?

Comment: Have you tried retrievig user from the database instead of session? Most likely EntityManager is not managing user entity so it is considering it as a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like this

`posts.php`

```
/**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Users", inversedBy="posts")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="uploader_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    protected $uploader;
```

and in `Users.php`

```
 /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Posts", mappedBy="uploader")
     **/
    protected $posts;
```

I think you don't need cascade in there